# Scan IP addresses on a wired network

Tags: networking, raspberrypi, wired, ip-address

My computer is connected to two wired networks and a wireless network, as you can see in the network settings:
[image: network settings]

The currently selected network is actually a Raspberry Pi Zero connected via a USB cable. I would like to know the IP address of the Pi itself, so hence my question:

How can I list all devices connected on a certain Wired network connection?

Comment: What about `sudo arp-scan --localnet`? You need to `sudo apt-get install arp-scan` first though.

Comment: @ByteCommander The problem is that that lists all of the IP address on all of the networks, instead of only a single one.

Comment: You can specify the network to scan by finding out your IP on that network and specifying that and the slice/subnet mask instead of `--localnet`. See `man arp-scan`. The IP and subnet mask can likely be found in the output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: Do you have an Ethernet connector like the one here:  http://raspi.tv/2015/ethernet-on-pi-zero-how-to-put-an-ethernet-port-on-your-pi ?

Comment: @Terrance No, it's connected using a USB cable. The RPi is set up to be a virtual ethernet adapter, as described [here](http://blog.gbaman.info/?p=791).

Comment: That's a virtual connection through the USB connector, not an actual Ethernet connection to your network.  That is a direct connection only to your computer.  The 4th step states "You can SSH into it using raspberrypi.local as the address. " which is setup by the RPi to your computer only.

Comment: @Terrance I think that tutorial is aimed at Windows, as it worked there after installing some apple print drivers. I can't get `raspberrypi.local` to work on Ubuntu though, so that's why I was looking for the IP.

Comment: Did you configure the SD card exactly the way the instruction say before you moved it to the RPi?  Since the RPi Zero is not connected to your physical network it will not get an IP address from it.  The `raspberrypi.local` would be identified from the avahi-daemon that should be running in your Ubuntu.  The instructions you put there state that you configure a file on the SD card before you put it in the RPi so that the modules load properly so your computer will see it.

Comment: @Terrance Yes I followed the tutorial, and I got it it work on a Windows 10 laptop. How can I check if the avahi-deamon is working correctly?

Comment: The only configuration for avahi-daemon is located at `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`.  It should be setup as a default configuration that should not need any configuration to work.  To check for it running, type in `ps -ef | grep avahi` from a command line and you should see it running.  If not, try installing it by `sudo apt install avahi-utils`.

Comment: @Terrance avahi-daemon is indeed running. I still can't figure out why I can't ssh into raspberrypi.local though...